# How much is an asset producing $X/month is worth?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, stock-markets, stock-valuation

Let's say there is an `asset` that produces $1000/month. There is a limited amount of them in total, let's say 1000 of them (each generating $1000/month). No more can be printed or generated.

This asset requires absolutely no maintenance, no supervision, no time investment, nothing. You just buy it and as long as you have it - it pays you $1000/month.

No risk of losing, getting stolen or confiscated by the government.

You can buy or sell this asset as easy as a company's share on stock exchange or just as easy as exchanging money to cryptocurrencies. So liquidity is super high.

What is a good way/formula to determine this asset's price?

Comment: Is this just another way to formulate the question that you deleted?

Comment: @DStanley yeah man, saw your answer, thanks, but thought I formed it incorrectly. This is just reformulation of the same thing.

Comment: OK I misread your other question.  I think you formulated it fine so that's my bad.

Comment: Looking up the value of a perpetuity would be a good place to start...

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is just to compute how much money you'd have to have invested elsewhere to provide a comparable return. For example, if you assume a safe interest rate of 2.3% per year, you would need to have about $520,000 to get $1,000/month.

Comment: so you are saying, this hypothetical asset is worth $520k?

Comment: If you think the long term, no risk interest rate is 2.3%. I think that's a reasonable value but others can disagree.

Comment: how did you calculate it? The investment breaks even only 43 years later.

Comment: Are you asking how I got 2.3%? Or how I got $520,000 from 2.3%?

Comment: how you got $520k for this hypothetical asset

Comment: That's in my answer. I just computed how much I'd have to invest elsewhere to get a comparable return. At a long-term interest rate of 2.3%, you'd have to invest $520,000 or so to get $1,000/month.

Comment: what was that elsewhere thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63687/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-gintas).

Comment: @Gintas_ The calculation is $1,000 divided by (2.3% divided by 12).  1000/0.001916 = 521000.  If you held $521,000 in an account earning at 2.3% per year it would kick off $1,000 per month (assuming a safe interest of 2.3% which is roughly what blended US treasury funds are earning currently.).

Comment: Actually the hypothetical investment would be worse than the 2.3% bank account, because the bank account will grow by compounding if the $1000 is left in the account each month. With no compounding the investment will eventually be worthless.

Comment: David - respectfully, you never actually offer the calculation. $1000/mo is $12K/yr. we usually quote interest on an annual basis. You chose 2.3%. I respect the thought behind it, but the question is theoretical and if we choose 2.5%, the math is easy - $12000/.025 is $480K easy head math as .025 = 1/40.  At 2%, 12000/.02= $600K.

Comment: @Victor I don't agree. The bank account will only compound if you don't pull out the $1,000/month. If the account is locked at the long-term inflation rate, as this investment is, then the compounding is precisely equal in value to the cash stream.